# WinRT ScrollViewer Zoom Bug?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I am having issues with WinRt's ScrollViewer. Consider this minimal sample:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <TextBlock Width="50" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Zooming in just a little will cut off the text at the top. You can't actually scroll that part into view anymore. Changing the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` also doesn't work.

Am I missing something or is this truly a bug?

EDIT: Can at least someone confirm this?

Comment: Ever hear anything about this?  Find a workaround/fix?

Comment: nope, I submitted the bug here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/915915/winrt-scrollviewer-zoom-bug nothing came out of it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not specifying the Height of the TextBlock.  I agree -- it shouldn't work this way but it does at the moment.  There are workarounds.  For example:
Modify TextBlock tag as follows:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

You can add a grid around the TextBlock and set the background color of the scrollview and grid to see whats going on:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Red">
        <Grid Width="50" Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="50">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```